# gradients of custom loss

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Suppose a model as in:

```
model = Model(inputs=[A, B], outputs=C)
```

With custom loss:

```
def actor_loss(y_true, y_pred):
   log_lik = y_true * K.log(y_pred)
   loss = -K.sum(log_lik * K.stop_gradient(B))
   return loss
```

Now I'm trying to define a function that returns the gradients of the loss wrt to the weights for a given pair of input and target output and expose it as such.
Here is an idea of what I mean in pseudocode

```
def _get_grads(inputs, targets):
   loss = model.loss(targets, model.output)
   weights = model.trainable_weights
   grads = K.gradients(loss, weights)
   model.input[0] (aka 'A') <----inputs[0]
   model.input[1] (aka 'B') <----inputs[1]
   return K.function(model.input, grads)

self.get_grads = _get_grads
```

My question is how do I feed inputs argument to the graph inside said function. 
(So far I've only worked with .fit and not with .gradients and I can't find any decent documentation with custom loss or multiple inputs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `K.function`, you get an actual callable function, so you should just call it with some parameter values. The format is exactly the same as `model.fit`, in your case it should be two arrays of values, including the batch dimension:

```
self.get_grads = _get_grads(inputs, targets)

grad_value = self.get_grads([input1, input2])
```

Where `input1` and `input2` are numpy arrays that include the batch dimension.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of K.function ,K.gradients and custom loss was fundamentally wrong. You use the function to construct a mini-graph that computes gradients of loss wrt to weights. No need for the function itself to have arguments.

```
def _get_grads():
   targets = Input(shape=...)
   loss = model.loss(targets, model.output)
   weights = model.trainable_weights
   grads = K.gradients(loss, weights)
   return K.function(model.input + [targets], grads)
```

I was under the impression that _get_grads was itself K.function but that was wrong. _get_grads() returns K.function. And then you use that as

```
f = _get_grads() # constructs the mini-graph that gives gradients
grads = f([inputs, labels])
```

inputs is fed to model.inputs, labels to targets and it returns grads.